# Prevent duplicate site elements being added to applicationHost.config when opening a ASP .Net Web App project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have an ASP .NET Web Application project Visual Studio 2013, which I use for testing purposes only. I'm using pretty much the default project setup:

- Running the project starts an IIS Express web service.
- The web application only accepts requests from `localhost` - other hosts results in a `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname` response.

I want to be able to send requests and recieve responses from another machine on my LAN. I was able to figure out that that this can be enabled by modified `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` file, changing the value of the `//configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/bindings/binding[@bindingInformation]` attribute from `*:1728:localhost` to `*:1728:*`.

This works, but there's another annoying problem: Whenever I reopen the project in Visual Studio, a duplicate `site` element is created in the `applicationHost.config` file with the old value of `*:1728:localhost` for the `bindingInformation` attribute, meaning I have to repeat the above process. Is there a way to get IIS Express/Visual Studio to use the existing, modified `site` configuration element rather than create a new one? Failing that, is there a way to change the default value for the `bindingInformation` attribute to `*:1728:localhost` instead of `*:1728:localhost`?

Answer (score 4):

Do not remove localhost from :1728:localhost.
Just duplicate :1728:localhost; :1728:192.168.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the `bindingInformation` in the already created bindings. Just add a new `binding` element. Like so:

```
<site name="SitenameHere" id="11">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\**usernameHere**\PathToProjectHere" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1728:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1728:*" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```