# Duplicate site section in applicationhost.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 project. When I restart Visual Studio (Version 16.8.4), a new section "site" is added to the applicationhost.config file. How can I fix it?

screenshot of ApplicationHost.config
[image: applicationhost.config]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent duplicate site elements being added to applicationHost.config when opening a ASP .Net Web App project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917942/prevent-duplicate-site-elements-being-added-to-applicationhost-config-when-openi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate question [Prevent duplicate site elements being added to applicationHost.config when opening a ASP .Net Web App project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917942/prevent-duplicate-site-elements-being-added-to-applicationhost-config-when-openi)